# Making a calculator in c, how to calculate more than 2 numbers

Tags: c

I have to make a calculator in c in which the program reads the mathematical operation in the first line and prints the result of it in the next line. Also an error message must be written if in the mathematical operation are characters that are not numbers. Right now my program only reads one mathematical operation in one line (ex. 2+5). Any ideas how it can read more operations in one line? (ex. 2+5+7+8)
My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch;
    int input1 = 0, input2 = 0, flag = 0, flag1 = 0;
    char oper;
    int i = 1;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
        int result = 0;
        if (ch != '\n'){ /* If user didnt change line */
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){ /* Checks if ch is a number */
                if(flag == 0) /* flag is used to change to the second number */
                    input1 = input1*10 + ch - '0'; /* Converts ASCII to decimal */
                else
                    input2 = input2*10 + ch - '0';  /* Converts ASCII to decimal*/
            }
            if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*'){ /* Operator has been detected */
                oper = ch;
                flag = 1;
            }
            if (ch >= 'A'){
                flag1 = 1; /* flag1 is used to determine if a non-number character was written */
            }   
        }
        else{
            switch(oper){
                case '+': /* if operator is "+" add the numbers */
                    result = input1 + input2;
                break;
                case '-': /* if operator is "-" subtract the numbers */
                    result = input1 - input2;
                break;
                case '*': /* if operator is "*" multiply the numbers */
                    result = input1 * input2;
                break;      
            }
            if (flag1 == 0){
                printf("Result %d: %d\n", i, result);
                i++;
                input1 = 0;
                input2 = 0;
                flag = 0;
            }
            else if (flag1 == 1){
                printf("Result %d: Error!\n", i);
                i++;
                input1 = 0;
                input2 = 0;
                flag = 0;
                flag1 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use an array for inputs (and loop)

Comment: Build a tree to handle the priority of `*` on `+`

Comment: @Ôrel what do you mean to build a tree?

Comment: https://medium.com/basecs/grammatically-rooting-oneself-with-parse-trees-ec9daeda7dad

Comment: there is no quick answer to this question, what you really want to craft is an interpreter.  However, you may want to take a look at http://www.craftinginterpreters.com/, chapter 6 (parsing expressions) http://www.craftinginterpreters.com/parsing-expressions.html has a bunch of useful information on how to parse expressions.  Best of luck.

Comment: There's a whole chapter dedicated to this in K & R. Worth a read. Also "Converts ASCII to decimal" is much better rephrased as "Converts to decimal".

Comment: tinyexpr is probably the smallest C math expression parser you will find: https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr You can either learn how it works, or just use it.

Comment: @Bathsheba which chapter is it?

Comment: @stefnto: I can't recall, but there's no harm in reading the whole book (and completing all the example exercises).

Comment: Read about [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)s

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prefix notation for easier calculating.
You have lots of online materials and code for infix-prefix notations.
The basic idea is that your input (e.g.: (1+2)*(3*4)), which represents infix notation, can be converted in prefix notation (*+12*34). Use *Stack data structure* to calculate given prefix structure.

***EVALUATE_PREFIX (STRING):***

So let's say you have: ***+12*34** like in our previous example.

1. Put a pointer at the end of the expression so that it points to number 4 in our example and then read the character.
2. If the character at pointer is an operand push it to Stack.
3. If the character at pointer is an operator pop two elements from the Stack. Operate on these elements, according to the operator, and push the result back to the Stack.
4. Decrement pointer by 1 and go to 2. step as long as there are characters left to be scanned in the expression.
5. When there are no more characters left *the result* is stored at the top of the Stack so just return it.

I suggest that you take a look at prefix, infix and postfix expressions. It won't take long to understand it and it should provide a good solution for your problem. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: What about the operator precedence?

Comment: You mean what about if the operator is inputted first (wrong input)? If that's the case, when converting from infix to prefix notation you can make that it prints error if input's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this a good exercise for myself =D
Pieces of suggestions:

- A state machine can help with getting the input
- In this case (calculator), a linked list should be sufficient to facilitate multiple operations
- fill the list up as you gather inputs, and then empty the list in the order of the operator priority

I tried put together some code, hope it is of help. Have not get the chance to compile and test though.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_SIZE 1000;
struct Node
{
    char operator;
    int result;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};

enum InputState{
    START = 0,
    NUMBER,
    OPERATOR
    };

void pushNodeToList( struct Node**head, struct Node**tail, char op, int result)
{
    struct Node* nodePtr = malloc(sizeof(*nodePtr));
    nodePtr->operator = op;
    result = result;
    if(!head)
    {
        *head = nodePtr;
        *tail = nodePtr;
        nodePtr->left = 0;
        nodePtr->right = 0;
    }
    else{
        nodePtr->left = *tail;
        (*tail)->right = nodePtr;
        *tail = nodePtr;
    }
}

void calculateNode( struct Node* nodePtr)
{
    if(nodePtr->left != 0 && nodePtr->right != 0)
    {
        if(nodePtr->left->operator == 'n' && nodePtr->right->operator == 'n' )
        {
            //calculate result
            switch(nodePtr->operator)
            {
                case '+':
                    nodePtr->result = nodePtr->left->result + nodePtr->right->result;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    nodePtr->result = nodePtr->left->result - nodePtr->right->result;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    nodePtr->result = nodePtr->left->result * nodePtr->right->result;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Calculation Error: %d \n", 5);
                    return;

            }
            //change type of node to 'n'
            nodePtr->operator == 'n';

            //reduce the numbers consumed
            struct Node* tempLeft = nodePtr->left;
            struct Node* tempRight = nodePtr->right;
            nodePtr->left = tempLeft->left;
            nodePtr->right = tempRight->right;
            free(tempLeft);
            free(tempRight);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Calculation Error: %d \n", 4);
            return;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Calculation Error: %d \n", 3);
        return;
    }
}

int main(void) {

int ch;
struct Node* head = 0;
struct Node* tail = 0;

//have a state machine to handle the logics related to parsing input
int num = 0;
enum InputState mState = START;

int i = 1;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    switch(mState)
    {
        case START:
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
                mState = NUMBER;
                num = 0;
                //initialize state to number
            }
            else if(ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*'){
                mState = OPERATOR;
                //initilize state to operator
            }
            else{
                //your error code
                printf("Input Error: %d \n", 1);
                return 0;
            }
        break;
        case NUMBER:
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
                num = num * 10 + ch - '0';
            }
            else if(ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*'){
                mState = OPERATOR;
                //we just got a number recorded
                pushNodeToList(&head,&tail,'n',num);//'n' for number
            }
            else{
                printf("Input Error: %d \n", 2);
                return 0;
            }
        break;
        case OPERATOR:
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
                mState = NUMBER;
                num = ch - '0';
            }
            else if(ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*'){
                pushNodeToList(&head,&tail,ch,0);//push in operator
            }
            else{
                printf("Input Error: %d \n", 3);
                return 0;
            }
        break;
    }
}
//terminal condition to push-in last number
if(mState == NUMBER)
{
    pushNodeToList(&head,&tail,'n',num);//'n' for number
}

//higher prioriety operation
struct Node* workingPtr = head;
while(workingPtr !=tail)//assuming the last input is number (not operator)
{
    if(workingPtr->operator == '*')
    {
        calculateNode(workingPtr);
    }
}
//lower prioriety operations
workingPtr = head;
while(workingPtr !=tail)
{
    if(workingPtr->operator == '+' || workingPtr->operator == '-' )
    {
        calculateNode(workingPtr);
    }
}
//print result
if(head == tail && head->operator == 'n')
{
    printf("Result : %d\n", head->result);
}
else
{
    printf("Error: %d \n", 7);
    return 0;
}


return 0;
}
```